# How to create cumstom TableViewCells dynamically in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic

I want to create custom TableViewCells and therefore I created some classes typeACell/typeBCell that extend from UITableViewCell.

Now in

```
tableView-cellForRowAtIndexPath -> UITableViewCell
```

I want to return the cells dynamically. How is it possible to return my custom cells when I want to create the return value only once via

```
let dynCell:UITableViewCell!
```

What do I have to change in my approach

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cellTypeSelector = DynamicCellSelector.getTypeAnyhow()
    let dynCell:UITableViewCell!

    if cellTypeSelector.isTypeA() {
        dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeACell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeACell
        (dynCell as! TypeACell).titleBar.text = ""
    }
    else if cellTypeSelector.isTypeB() {
        dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeBCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeBCell
        (dynCell as! TypeBCell).titleBar.text = ""
    }
    else {
        dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("unknownTypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UnknownTypeCell
        (dynCell as! UnknownTypeCell).titleBar.text = ""
    }

    return dynCell
}
```

This throws the error:

> Variable 'dynCell' used before being initialized

Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I change my let to var and unpack the values it seems to work - but is this the correct way?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cellTypeSelector = DynamicCellSelector.getTypeAnyhow()
    var dynCell:UITableViewCell!

    if cellTypeSelector.isTypeA() {
        dynCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeACell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeACell)!
        (dynCell as! TypeACell).titleBar.text = ""
    }
    else if cellTypeSelector.isTypeB() {
        dynCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeBCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeBCell)!
        (dynCell as! TypeBCell).titleBar.text = ""
    }
    else {
        dynCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("unknownTypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UnknownTypeCell)!
        (dynCell as! UnknownTypeCell).titleBar.text = ""
    }

    return dynCell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this(using your code):

```
    let cellTypeSelector = DynamicCellSelector.getTypeAnyhow()
    let dynCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeACell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeACell;
    if cellTypeSelector.isTypeB() {
        dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeBCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeBCell
        (dynCell as! TypeBCell).titleBar.text = ""
    }else{
        (dynCell as! TypeACell).titleBar.text = ""
    }

    return dynCell
```

Comment: For TypeB tableview will be dequeued cell twice, it is not good.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because the condition for initializing cell is unclear. First `if` statement has an `else` branch, but the second `if` statement does not. If both conditions are false, the cell will remain uninitialized.

You can fix this by adding a second `else` branch:

```
if cellTypeSelector.isTypeA() {
    dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeACell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeACell
    (dynCell as! TypeACell).titleBar.text = ""
}
else if cellTypeSelector.isTypeB() {
    dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeBCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeBCell
    (dynCell as! TypeBCell).titleBar.text = ""
}
else {
    dynCell = UITableViewCell()
}

return dynCell
```

Or you can remove second `if` statement if you are sure that cell will be TypeB:

```
if cellTypeSelector.isTypeA() {
    dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeACell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeACell
    (dynCell as! TypeACell).titleBar.text = ""
}
else {
    dynCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("typeBCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TypeBCell
    (dynCell as! TypeBCell).titleBar.text = ""
}

return dynCell
```

Comment: thanx for your answer! unfort. I forgot the last block of code to add which was this else block you are talking about. I edited my code above. but even with this else statement the error keeps be throwing...